# Simultaneously modify different keys in ZODB

Tags: python, transactions, zodb

I'm using ZODB as a persistent storage for objects that are going to be modified through a webservice.
Below is an example to which I reduced the issue.
The increment-function is what is called from multiple threads.
My problem is, that when increment is called simultaneously from two threads, for different keys, I'm getting the conflict-error.

I imagine it should be possible to resolve this, at least as long different keys are modified, in a proper way?
If so, I didn't manage to find an example on how to... (the zodb-documentation seems to be somewhat spread across different sites :/ )

Glad about any ideas...

```
import time
import transaction
from ZODB.FileStorage import FileStorage
from ZODB.DB import DB
from ZODB.POSException import ConflictError

def test_db():
    store = FileStorage('zodb_storage.fs')
    return DB(store)

db_test = test_db()     

# app here is a flask-app
@app.route('/increment/<string:key>')
def increment(key):
    '''increment the value of a certain key'''

    # open connection
    conn = db_test.open()
    # get the current value:
    root = conn.root()
    val = root.get(key,0)    

    # calculate new value 
    # in the real application this might take some seconds
    time.sleep(0.1)
    root[key] = val + 1     

    try:
        transaction.commit()
        return '%s = %g' % (key, val)
    except ConflictError:
        transaction.abort()
        return 'ConflictError :-('
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options here: implement conflict resolution, or retry the commit with fresh data.

[Conflict resolution](http://docs.zope.org/zope3/Code/ZODB/ConflictResolution.txt/index.html) only applies to custom types you store in the ZODB, and can only be applied if you know how to merge your change into the newly-changed state.

The ZODB looks for a `_p_resolveConflict()` method on custom types and calls that method with the old state, the saved state you are in conflict with, and the new state you tried to commit; you are supposed to return the merged state. For a simple counter, like in your example, that'd be a as simple as updating the saved state with the change between the old and new states:

```
class Counter(Persistent):
    def __init__(self, start=0):
        self._count = start

    def increment(self):
        self._count += 1
        return self._count

    def _p_resolveConflict(self, old, saved, new):
        # default __getstate__ returns a dictionary of instance attributes
        saved['_count'] += new['_count'] - old['_count']
        return saved
```

The other option is to retry the commit; you want to limit the number of retries, and you probably want to encapsulate this in a decorator on your method, but the basic principle is that you loop up to a limit, make your calculations based on ZODB data (which, after a conflict error, will auto-read fresh data where needed), then attempt to commit. If the commit is successful you are done:

```
max_retries = 10
retry = 0

conn = db_test.open()
root = conn.root()

while retry < max_retries:
    val = root.get(key,0)    
    time.sleep(0.1)
    root[key] = val + 1

    try:
        transaction.commit()
        return '%s = %g' % (key, val)
    except ConflictError:
        retry += 1

raise CustomExceptionIndicatingTooManyRetries
```

Comment: Shouldn't the conflict resolution for the counter be `saved['_count'] += new['_count'] - old['_count']` so as to handle the case of `increment()` being called more than once?

Comment: @Duncan: hrm, true. In fact, that's exactly what `BTree.Length` does.. I'll update.

Comment: In fact, my issue was more about changing two different keys in parallel, two instances of a Counter in your example. Turns out this is solved by introducing the Counter class, instead of just writing plain numbers into "root". Which is, i assume, due to the fact that the (mutabl) root doesn't actually change anymore?

Comment: Indeed, *any* two threads changing the same object (the root in this case) trigger a conflict.